# How do I alphabetically sort a list in HTML with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have 2 html files `index.html` and `list.html`. When i load the list.html to index.html I want it automatically sort to alphabetical.

**index.html:**

```
<button onclick="javascript:showlist()">Show</button>
<div id="content"></div>
```

**list.html:**

```
<ul id="myUL">
<li>SUPERMAN</li>
<li>BATMAN</li>
<li>FLASH</li>
<li>ANARKY</li>
</ul>
```

**js:**

```
function showlist(){
  $("#content").load("list.html");
  sortList();
}

function sortList() {
  var list, i, switching, b, shouldSwitch;
  list = document.getElementById("myUL");
  switching = true;
  /* Make a loop that will continue until
  no switching has been done: */
  while (switching) {
    // start by saying: no switching is done:
    switching = false;
    b = list.getElementsByTagName("li");
    // Loop through all list-items:
    for (i = 0; i < (b.length - 1); i++) {
      // start by saying there should be no switching:
      shouldSwitch = false;
      /* check if the next item should
      switch place with the current item: */
      if (b[i].innerHTML.toLowerCase() > b[i + 1].innerHTML.toLowerCase()) {
        /* if next item is alphabetically
        lower than current item, mark as a switch
        and break the loop: */
        shouldSwitch = true;
        break;
      }
    }
    if (shouldSwitch) {
      /* If a switch has been marked, make the switch
      and mark the switch as done: */
      b[i].parentNode.insertBefore(b[i + 1], b[i]);
      switching = true;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I converted this to a snippet, haven't posted the edit because it works. What is the question? This already works

Comment: it's already been answered. But the question is from 2 different file. If i do this everytime i load the list from my index it was not sort alphabetically. And you need to create a button for sortList() just to make it sort (a-z)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The part that's missing is the [onload handler](https://api.jquery.com/load/). Without that, you're probably calling `sortList()` before the content has loaded. Otherwise your function works

```
$("#content").load("list.html", function() {
    console.log("Loaded");
    sortList();
})
```

Answer (score 2):

you can't sort your list before when it was loaded
you need to use the event load over your div
code it this way:

```
function showlist() {
  $('#content').load('list.html');
}

const contentDiv = document.querySelector('#content')

contentDiv.onload =_=> 
  {
  const
    list  = contentDiv.querySelector(`ul`)
  , arrLI = [...list.querySelectorAll('li')]
      .map(li=>({key:li.textContent.toLowerCase(),li}))
      .sort((a,b)=>a.key.localeCompare(b.key))

  arrLI.forEach(el=>list.appendChild(el.li) ) 
  }
```

here is the code to demonstrate how the sort works:

```js
sortList('#content')

function sortList( parentDiv )
  {
  const
    list  = document.querySelector(`${parentDiv} > ul`)
  , arrLI = [...list.querySelectorAll('li')]
      .map(li=>({key:li.textContent.toLowerCase(),li}))
      .sort((a,b)=>a.key.localeCompare(b.key))

  arrLI.forEach(el=>list.appendChild(el.li) ) 
  }
```

```html
<div id="content">
  <ul>
    <li>SUPERMAN</li>
    <li>BATMAN</li>
    <li>FLASH</li>
    <li>ANARKY</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: the thing is my list is from other file intentionally and i just needed it to call from my index and show it to specific div.

Comment: @Asklepiades this is just to show how it works. You may use `sortList('#content')` into your `load` function

Comment: @Asklepiades I added to my answer a way to use it

Answer (score 0):

As the accepted answer mentions, you have to run your sort code in the [.load()](https://api.jquery.com/load/) callback. But I'm going to answer again anyway because that is some narley sorting code you have there. You can use [.append()](https://api.jquery.com/append/), [.detach()](https://api.jquery.com/detach/) and [.sort()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) for much cleaner code.

```
$('#content').load('list.html', function() {
  $('ul').append($('li').detach().sort((a, b) => a.textContent > b.textContent));
});
```